# Replace block of text in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, text, replace, multiline

is there any way how to replace block of text (multi-line) in VS2008(VS2005)?  So far I know VS2008 supports only single line replacing.

Any tips welcome, cheers X.

EDIT: thanks for tips guys. I was rather looking for some simplier option: like select multiline text, click Ctrl+H, Ctrl+V (copy text from memory) and hit Replace All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL+H -> Find Options -> Use Regular Expressions | WildCards.  Then you can push on the right arrow next to the "Find What" and "Replace With" textboxes and see what you can use. Descriptions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87a13zt0.aspx).

Comment: I think this is the closest possible answer. However I was just looking for some option to use simply Ctrl+H for multilane selected text. Without any special setting.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2005 (and maybe before) supports regular expressions, permitting the selection and replacement of multi-line text.